# SUM(), GROUP BY, and WHERE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like this:

```
Title   | Version   | Condition | Count
-----------------------------------------------
Title1  | 1.0       | 1         | 10
Title1  | 1.1       | 2         | 5
Title1  | 1.1       | 2         | 10
Title1  | 1.1       | 1         | 10
Title2  | 1.0       | 2         | 10
Title2  | 1.5       | 1         | 5
Title2  | 1.5       | 2         | 5
Title3  | 1.5       | 2         | 10
Title3  | 1.5       | 1         | 10
```

And I would like to sum the value of "Count" for each line that has the MAX() "Version", and "Condition" = 2. I'd like this to be the resulting data set:

```
Title   | Version   | Condition | Count
-----------------------------------------------
Title1  | 1.1       | 2         | 15
Title2  | 1.5       | 2         | 5
Title3  | 1.5       | 2         | 10
```

I am able to get the list of "Title" And MAX("Version") with "Condition" = 2 with:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Title, MAX(Version) AS MaxVer FROM TABLE
WHERE Condition = 2
GROUP BY Title
```

Bit I'm not sure how to add all the "Count"s.

Comment: ,SUM(Count) as Count

Comment: Just a side remark concerning your own query: you group by title, so you get one row per title. Accordingly the resulting rows are distinct (they all have different titles). There is no sense in applying `DISTINCT` on the rows hence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.Title, t1.Version, t1.Condition, SUM([Count]) AS Count
FROM mytable AS t1
JOIN (
  SELECT Title, MAX(Version) AS max_version
  FROM mytable
  WHERE Condition = 2
  GROUP BY Title
) AS t2 ON t1.Title = t2.Title AND t1.Version = t2.max_version
WHERE t1.Condition = 2
GROUP BY t1.Title, t1.Version, t1.Condition
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/12e0f5/1)

Comment: why the single quotes around count?

Comment: @pyNoob I thought it was a MySQL question, my bad :=(

Comment: No worries, you provided an excellent solution in fast timing  :)  Just wanted to point it out in case someone tried to use it and got an error.

Comment: You missed Version and Condition in the GROUP BY, but other than that - excellent answer! :)

Comment: @DavidBachmannJeppesen Thanks David, I've corrected my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This needs only a single access to the table:

```
SELECT Title, Version, Condition, Count
FROM
 ( -- calculate all SUMs
   SELECT Title, Version, Condition, SUM(Count) AS Count,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Title ORDER BY Version DESC) AS rn
   FROM TABLE
   WHERE Condition = 2
   GROUP BY Title, Version, Condition
 ) AS dt
   -- and return only the row with the highest Version
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: Small mistake: You sum the counts in the subquery, so you should only access this result in the main query and must not sum again.

Comment: Have you tested this query? As far as I know, you can not use a window-function (ROW_NUMBER()) in a block that has a GROUP BY.

Comment: @DavidBachmannJeppesen: You can easily mix Aggregates and Windowed Aggregates, those OLAP-functions are processed *after* GROUP BY/HAVING, e.g. RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(column) DESC)`

Comment: @dnoeth: Okay. I know for a fact that Oracle SQL does not allow it, but I must admit that I have not tested it on T-SQL. Sorry. :)

Comment: @DavidBachmannJeppesen: Every DBMS allows it, see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/60c34/8 :-)

Comment: The version of Oracle that I have the most experience with, did not, but I guess they upgraded then? Thanks for the heads up! :)